# I run into a 500 Internal Server Error each time I go on a route with a parameter

Tags: apache, symfony, xampp, composer-php, internal-server-error

I've set up a symfony website on my Windows11 computer using xampp and composer. I have coded multiple routes within my controllers, and they all run perfectly fine except for the ones taking in a parameter. I've looked through the apache error log, which indicates there's a problem with "LimitInternalRecursion". I have tried a few things (changing the .htaccess file of the project, looking for any directive related to recursion inside the apache configuration file) and none of them have worked. I've even erased then re-created the project, just in case. It didn't change much, as one would expect.

(Disclaimer, this website is for a class in University, so the code might not look great. Additionally, it is a shortened version.)

Here's the controller file's code

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use App\Entity\Film;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Entity\Studio;
use App\Form\FilmType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FilmController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/film', name: 'app_film')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('film/index.html.twig', ['controller_name' => 'FilmController',]);
    }

    #[Route('/ajoutFilm', name: 'app_ajoutFilm')]
    public function ajoutFilmAction(ManagerRegistry $doctrine){
        $film1 = new Film();
        
        $film1->setTitre("titreFilm");
        $date = new \DateTime('2012-10-12');
        $film1->setDateSortie($date);
        $film1->setResume("resumeFilm");

        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($film1);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('film/index.html.twig', ['controller_name' => 'FilmController',]);
    }

    #[Route('/ajoutStudio', name: 'app_ajoutStudio')]
    public function ajoutStudioAction(ManagerRegistry $doctrine){
        $studio1 = new Studio();
        $nom = "Ankama";
        $pays = "France";
                $studio1->setNom($nom);
        $studio1->setPays($pays);

        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($studio1);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('film/index.html.twig', ['controller_name' => 'FilmController',]);
    }

    #[Route('/afficherFilm/{id}', name: 'app_afficherFilm')]
    public function afficherFilmAction($id, ManagerRegistry $doctrine){
        $film = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(Film::class)->find($id);
        return $this->render("film/unFilm.html.twig", array('unFilm' => $film));
    }
}
?>
```

the related twig page code

```
Titre du film : <b>{{ unFilm.titre }}</b><br>
Date de sortie : {{ unFilm.dateSortie|date("d/m/Y") }}<br>
Résumé : {{ unFilm.resume }}<br>
```

the .htaccess file

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and an extract of the log file

> 

[Tue Nov 08 16:41:21.022703 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9828:tid 336] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 08 16:41:34.378207 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1880] [client ::1:50530] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/
[Tue Nov 08 17:29:19.411628 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1868] [client ::1:63702] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/ajout
[Tue Nov 08 17:35:12.978177 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1832] [client ::1:63794] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/ajout
[Tue Nov 08 17:41:27.403631 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1856] [client ::1:63839] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/ajoutStudio
[Tue Nov 08 20:31:47.830001 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1868] [client ::1:64153] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/ajoutStudio
[Tue Nov 08 20:32:32.627400 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1828] [client ::1:64195] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://symfony-formation6.localhost/ajoutStudio
[Tue Nov 08 20:43:29.700279 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1856] [client ::1:64295] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Nov 08 21:05:21.818949 2022] [core:error] [pid 9828:tid 1868] [client ::1:55233] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

> 

As suggested, I have changed the log level and tried two more times. The error log now contains :

> 

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:error] [pid 10260:tid 1932] [client ::1:49881] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3956): [client ::1:49881] AH00121: r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.166236 2022] [core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1932] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49881] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/1

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.218406 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49882] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: symfony-formation6.localhost/afficherFilm/1

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.218406 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49882] AH01626: authorization result of : granted, referer: symfony-formation6.localhost/afficherFilm/1

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.219427 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49882] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: symfony-formation6.localhost/afficherFilm/1

[Sun Nov 13 20:33:46.219427 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10260:tid 1888] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49882] AH01626: authorization result of : granted, referer: symfony-formation6.localhost/afficherFilm/1

> 

and

> 

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:30.921017 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 31064:tid 340] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:30.929095 2022] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1912] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:443 using AcceptFilter none

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:30.929095 2022] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1920] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:443 using AcceptFilter none

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:30.929095 2022] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1940] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:80 using AcceptFilter none

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:30.929095 2022] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1956] child.c(430): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:80 using AcceptFilter none

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.657135 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.657135 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.658170 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.658170 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.658170 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.658170 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.659169 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.659169 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.660431 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.660964 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.660964 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.660964 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.661977 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.661977 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.663003 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.663003 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.663976 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.663976 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.664976 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.664976 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client ::1:49950] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:error] [pid 31064:tid 1884] [client ::1:49950] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3956): [client ::1:49950] AH00121: r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/index.php

[Sun Nov 13 20:43:50.665991 2022] [core:debug] [pid 31064:tid 1884] core.c(3969): [client ::1:49950] AH00123: subrequested from r->uri = /afficherFilm/1

> 

I hope it helps. Sorry if it doesn't, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: symfony installations come with a .htaccess in their project dir, and require very little redirection/rewriting in the main apache config. I would suggest you adapt the apache main config to match the one here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html . It is very likely, that there is some infinite loop going on between the main config and the .htaccess (and possibly the controller). check the network log of the browser, too. it's usually some shenanigans adding and removing the trailing slash. (can't say, why the parameter would trigger this though)

Comment: Please share more details. Is this really a problem related to Composer? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know for sure. All I know is that whenever there's a "{var}" in the Route, it causes an error. I haven't tried anything because I don't want to mess with the directives in the .htaccess file and the configuration file for the xampp server doesn't seem to contain anything related to the error I found in the error log

Comment: @Jakumi I'm going to try that

Comment: Set Apache logging to debug level and also enable the rewrite log. It will produce some more data (much more) that will hopefully help you to better understand the effects of your configuration changes (on server level).

Comment: @hakre I've done some more tinkering, and it seems the problem isn't the « {id} », but the fact there's a second « / » in the URL

Comment: Big update, I've resolved the issue by replacing the 2nd « / » by an equal sign (=). Thanks everyone! (By the way, how do I close this post ?)